# Calculating the exact positions of(Td, TD, Tm, cm, T*) content stream in pdf?

Tags: pdf, accessibility, pdfbox, tagging, pdf-manipulation

Getting or calculating the  exact positions of(Td, TD, Tm, cm, T*) content stream in pdf?

As a human I am able to calculate(whether it is replacing last Td or adding to last Td or multiplication with fontsize) the positions of tags in pdf content stream by comparing , where the  glyphs  are located in pdf and content stream  position values. But I am unable to calculate  perfect positions of glyph's programatically . Please see the screen short.

In above image left side box is pdf ui glyphs and right side box contains the related content stream. In content stream I highlighted two Td positions.

In first circle

3.321 -6.475999832 Td

The Td positions should add to the last Td positions. Assume x1, y1.

Current_x_pos = x1+3.321

Curent_y_pos = y1-6.475999832

then we can get the exact position of glyph "t".

In second highlighted circle the new Td positions (231.544 366.377990 Td) are completely replaced like

Current_x_pos = 231.544

Curent_y_pos = 366.377990

Along with that some times the parent tag is Tm at that case the formula might be like this

Current_x_pos = x1+(tdx1*font_size)

Curent_y_pos = y1+(tdy1*font_size)

**When we need to multiply like above, and some times addition. Programatically how can I know this. To parse exact positions?**(new screen short added for multiplication)

Any help ?
Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did my answer appropriately explain the observations?

Comment: @mkl yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When we need to multiply like above, and some times addition. Programatically how can I know this. To parse exact positions?

It's quite simple, for a **Td** operation you **always** multiply, see the specification ISO 32000-1 (similarly in ISO 32000-2):

[image: excerpt from ISO 32000-1]

For a freshly initialized (i.e. identity) text line matrix T<sub>lm</sub> this matrix multiplication looks like **replacing its bottom row** with *t<sub>x</sub> t<sub>y</sub> 1*.

For a text line matrix T<sub>lm</sub> with only changes in the bottom row against an identity this matrix multiplication looks like an **addition to the bottom row**, e.g. *x y 1* becomes *x+t<sub>x</sub> y+t<sub>y</sub> 1*.

For a text line matrix T<sub>lm</sub> like in your second example

```
a 0 0
0 a 0
x y 1
```

this matrix multiplication looks like a **multiplication with *a* followed by an addition to the bottom row**, i.e. *x y 1* becomes *x+a·t<sub>x</sub> y+a·t<sub>y</sub> 1*. If the *font size* parameter of the preceding **Tf** operation was *1*, then *a* would effectively be the resultant font size giving rise to your assumption the font size is part of the formula.

In general, for an arbitrary, non-degenerate text line matrix T<sub>lm</sub>

```
a b 0
c d 0
x y 1
```

this matrix multiplication looks **even more complex**, *x y 1* becomes *x+a·t<sub>x</sub>+c·t<sub>y</sub> y+b·t<sub>x</sub>+d·t<sub>y</sub> 1*.

Thus, concerning your question

> Programatically how can I know this. To parse exact positions?

your program should **simply always use matrix multiplication** and ignore what it looks like on the level of the separate coordinates.

---

What makes the second circled instruction look like a mere replacement, is that the prior text line matrix is the identity matrix. This is not due to the restore-state operation as assumed by François, though, but more simply to the start of text object operation **BT**:

[image: excerpt from ISO 32000-1]

As the text matrix and the text line matrix are reset at the start of a text object and the graphics state cannot be saved or restored in a text object, the save and restore graphics state operations are not to blame in this case.

*(Screen shots are from the ISO 32000-1 copy shared by Adobe.)*

Comment: I encountered some weird situation. You can see in this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kugh4PrEhIeWrxjcixsHn_6ADKam3NBs/view?usp=sharing . The first number calculation is identity matrix X [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [316.971, 65.348, 1] ] = [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [316.971, 65.348, 1] ] in my stack. 2. Will be [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [316.971, 65.348, 1] ] X [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [369.53, 87.47, 1] ] = [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [686.501, 152.818, 1] ] this is wrong calculation right? In this case it's should multiply with identity matrix. simply merely replacement. How can I know this?

Comment: Please make this a question in its own right. I'll look into that next week when I'm back in office.

Comment: created new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573104/ctm-matrix-multiplication-with-previous-state-vs-with-identity-matrix-in-pdf-pos

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

> In second highlighted circle the new Td positions (231.544 366.377990
>   Td) are completely replaced

Actually, the positions `Current_x_pos` and `Current_x_pos` are not replaced. This `Td` command does exactly like always:

```
Current_x_pos = x1 + 231.544
Curent_y_pos = y1 - 366.377990
```

It is the `Q` from 3 line above that reloads previous graphic state, right after the current graphic state has been saved with `q`.

Comment: I encountered some weird situation. You can see in screen link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kugh4PrEhIeWrxjcixsHn_6ADKam3NBs/view?usp=sharing
1. The first number calculation is identity matrix X [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [316.971, 65.348, 1] ] = [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [316.971, 65.348, 1] ]  in my stack. 
2. Will be  [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [316.971, 65.348, 1] ] X  [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [369.53, 87.47, 1] ] =    [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [686.501, 152.818, 1] ]
this is wrong calculation right? In this case it's should multiply with identity matrix.
simply merely replacement. How?